# Change Color of Text on Pivot Chart Data Label

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the data label colour from black to white on the chart.
I'm so close - but I can't seem to get it.
Help appreciated.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not pt Is Nothing Then
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered)
    With shp.Chart
    On Error Resume Next
        .SetSourceData pt.TableRange2
        .ShowAllFieldButtons = False
        .SeriesCollection("No").Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection("Yes").Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        '.SeriesCollection("No").Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .SeriesCollection("No").DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1
        .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
    End With
    Set pt = Nothing
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
On Error Resume Next
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not pt Is Nothing Then
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered)
    With shp.Chart
        On Error Resume Next
        .SetSourceData pt.TableRange2
        .ShowAllFieldButtons = False
        .SeriesCollection("No").Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection("Yes").Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .SeriesCollection("No").DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .SeriesCollection("Yes").DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1
        .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
    End With
    Set pt = Nothing
End If
```

I added a line to set the data label color for the "Yes" series as well to ensure both series' data labels appear with white text color. The line `.SeriesCollection("Yes").DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)` sets the text color of the "Yes" series' data labels to white.